# Eclipse Problem in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: eclipse

I recently installed eclipse but its not starting when i enter command "eclipse" on terminal. I am pasting a log, Kindly review it and suggest solution to fix the problem

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=kg8UvPEe

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165693/eclipse-cannot-load-swt-libraries

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. I edit the command to:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/
```

And on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit try:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/
```